# Dynamic Route 53 records for ACM certificate validation

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a Route 53 zone (example.org) with a few record sets (example.org, sub1.example.org). I also have an ACM certificate with DNS validation for the domains described by the record sets.
All of this is described in Terraform.
Currently for the validation to work I have to list all of the domain names in the certificate (`domain_name`, `subject_alternative_names`), the certificate validation (`validation_record_fqdns`), and the Route 53 records (`aws_route53_record` resources).
Is there a better, more dynamic way of doing this so if I want to add a new subdomain I only have to do so in one place?
I read about the `for` and `for_each` features in recent versions of Terraform but so far it's not trivial for me to use that in this case.

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "example" {
  domain_name               = "example.org"
  subject_alternative_names = ["sub1.example.org"]
  validation_method         = "DNS"
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "example" {
  certificate_arn         = "${aws_acm_certificate.example.arn}"
  validation_record_fqdns = ["${aws_route53_record.example-validation.fqdn}", "${aws_route53_record.example-validation-sub1.fqdn}"]
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "example-validation" {
  zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.example.id}"
  name    = "${aws_acm_certificate.example.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_name}"
  type    = "${aws_acm_certificate.example.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_type}"
  ttl     = 60
  records = ["${aws_acm_certificate.example.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_value}"]
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "example-validation-sub1" {
  zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.example.id}"
  name    = "${aws_acm_certificate.example.domain_validation_options.1.resource_record_name}"
  type    = "${aws_acm_certificate.example.domain_validation_options.1.resource_record_type}"
  ttl     = 60
  records = ["${aws_acm_certificate.example.domain_validation_options.1.resource_record_value}"]
}
```